# Change text color in fragment listview with adapter on menu item click

Tags: android

Good Day to all, In this application, need to change text color on menu item click. Textview is in custom row layout which inflated by adapter and adapter set in two fragments Tab layout. On menu item, click needs to change text color of listview whole listview. On normal application, its work fine but on a fragment, it gives error "Adaptor.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference" If anyone can give help. Thank you
Problem is that adapter is not initialized in main activity it initialized in fragment.SO in each fragment needsome think like

```
public void setColor(int color) 
 adapter.setTextColor(color); 
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

AND it MAIN ACTIVITY option menu

```
Fragment fragment=new Fragment(); 
fragment.setColor(Color.BLACK); –
```

MainActivity.java

```
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
 private ViewPager mViewPager;
   NewsAdaptor adaptor;

protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener(mViewPager));
}


  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu ) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.chagecolor) {
        Fragment fragment=new Fragment(); 
         fragment.setColor(Color.BLACK); –

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

newsApapter.java

```
public class NewsAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
TextView tvtitle;
private int color;
Context context;

public NewsAdaptor ( Context context, ArrayList <NewsItem> newsList ) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newsList = newsList;
    this.color = Color.RED;
}

ArrayList<NewsItem> newsList;

@Override
public int getCount () {

    return newsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem ( int position ) {
    return newsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId ( int position ) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent ) {
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView=View.inflate(context, R.layout.newsitemlist_layout,null);
    }
    NewsItem currentNews = newsList.get(position);
    tvtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1id);
    tvtitle.setText(currentNews.getTitle());
    tvtitle.setTextColor(color);
    return convertView;
}
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;

}
```

}

Now it in a fragment which whare adapter is implemented

TRADE .java

```
public class TRADE extends Fragment {


public TRADE () {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItemsList;

ListView ali;
NewsAdaptor adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trade, container, false);
      newsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
      ali = (ListView)view. findViewById(R.id.listtrade);
       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("https://urdu.geo.tv/rss/1/3", new Response.Listener <String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse ( String response ) {
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
            Elements itemElements = document.getElementsByTag("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
                Element item = itemElements.get(i);
                String title = rem(item.child(0).text());

                NewsItem news = new NewsItem();
                news.title = title;
                newsItemsList.add(news);
            }
            adapter = new NewsAdaptor(getContext(), newsItemsList);
            ali.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse ( VolleyError error ) {


        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
  public void setColor(int color) 
  adapter.setTextColor(color); 
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

SPORT.java

```
public class TRADE extends Fragment {


public SPORT() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
ArrayList<NewsItem> newsItemsList;

ListView ali;
NewsAdaptor adapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView ( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_trade, container, false);
      newsItemsList = new ArrayList<>();
      ali = (ListView)view. findViewById(R.id.listtrade);
       RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
      StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest("https://urdu.geo.tv/rss/1/3", new Response.Listener <String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse ( String response ) {
            Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
            Elements itemElements = document.getElementsByTag("item");
            for (int i = 0; i < itemElements.size(); i++) {
                Element item = itemElements.get(i);
                String title = rem(item.child(0).text());

                NewsItem news = new NewsItem();
                news.title = title;
                newsItemsList.add(news);
            }
            adapter = new NewsAdaptor(getContext(), newsItemsList);
            ali.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse ( VolleyError error ) {


        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    public void setColor(int color) 
    adapter.setTextColor(color); 
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); }
```

newsitemlist_layout.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1id"
    android:layout_width="237dp"
    android:layout_height="83dp"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/pubDateid"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="News TITLE"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not saying to adapter that you made a change.

```
public void setTextColor(int color) {
    this.color = color;
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Problem is that adapter is not initialized in main activity it initialized in fragment.SO in each fragment needsome think like                                                                  public void setColor(int color) {
        adapter.setTextColor(color);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); } AND it MAIN ACTIVITY option menu   Fragment fragment=new Fragment();
           fragment.setColor(Color.BLACK);

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity:

```
@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected ( MenuItem item ) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.chagecolor) {
        adaptor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

When `adaptor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);` is called, the `adaptor` field is `null` as you have never set it. Somewhere in the MainActivity you must do `adaptor=...`

Comment: adaptor=... what  I just edit some think to top of my question can you check

Comment: You have 2 variables: `adaptor` and `adapter`. One is in the MainActivity and IS NEVER INITIALISED and the second one is in your Fragment. So initialise the one in MainActivity and the problem will be solved. But I don't know why you need it in MainActivity if the Adapter is managed by the Fragment

Comment: no problem what needed is on options menu click should change text color if use  setHasOptionsMenu(true); it fragment it change color of one fragment need to change text color of of all tabs

Comment: on option menu click need to pass value of text color and change text color